# Create a generic method to modify a reference list of unknown type

Tags: c#, .net

I have few database scripts that all contains a List of there own type.

Like the example below:

```
public class FooDatabase()
{
    public List<Bar> myCollection;
}
```

Than I have more database with the same format:

```
public class OtherDatabase()
{
    public List<OtherBar> myCollection;
}
```

The items in the List always have an int ID regardless of what type they are.

Now I'm looking to implement a generic method that takes the ref collection and do some operations on it. The problem is if I give them an interface than I can't modify the ref collection.

```
public static void FillDatabase<T>(ref List<T> collection, string folderName)
{
    collection = new List<T>();

    List<T> foundItems = Resources.LoadAll(folderName, typeof(T)).ToList();

    // I need to make changes to the ID field regardless of which collection and type is passed in
    // Can't do the following, because it doesn't know it has the field ID
    foundItems.Find(item => item.ID == 0);

}
```

I tried to change the list to one of type `List<IDatabaseEntry>` with the IDatabaseEntry containing the ID field and having every class from every database implement that interface. The problem is that than I can't modify the original collection reverenced because the original collection isn't of type `List<IDatabaseEntry>`

Appreciate any help pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Why are you using `ref`?

Comment: You can declare that a generic method has to implement an interface. 
and then the interface has to be present on your Bar, aswell as you OtherBar. (any any other object, then your code should work)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Once T is defined as must having the interface on it, then you can presume the ID property will always be present.

Comment: @Crowcoder because I'm using ScriptableObjects in unity and the data is not persisted if not using ref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void FillDatabase<T>(ref List<T> collection, string folderName) where T : IDatabaseEntry
{
    collection = new List<T>();

    List<T> foundItems = Resources.LoadAll(folderName, typeof(T)).ToList();

    // I need to make changes to the ID field regardless of which collection and type is passed in
    // Can't do the following, because it doesn't know it has the field ID
    foundItems.Find(item => item.ID == 0);

}
```

Should fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach - if you have types with different `ID` types or properties you can pass `Func` returning `ID` as one of the parameters:

```
public static void FillDatabase<T, TKey>(ref List<T> collection, 
    string folderName, 
    Func<T, TKey> idGetter)
{
    collection = new List<T>();

    List<T> foundItems = Resources.LoadAll(folderName, typeof(T)).ToList();

    foundItems.Find(item => idGetter(item) == default(TKey));
}
```